# How to extend a sealed class - need simple program explanation and usage in real time

Tags: c#, .net

Folks

I have a sealed class as follows. I want to extend this sealed class so as to add a method which will return average of x and y. This is not just extension method using "this" :( Could someone please help me understand the concept of "Extending Sealed class" and its "Real time usage and benefits"

```
class Sealed A       
{ 
    int a; int b;    
    int Add (int x, int y)    
    {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Thank you....

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a book or tutorial. And, namely, the entire point of *sealed* is that you cannot extend it.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - Surviving without WSOIN?

Comment: Sorry :( I was asked this in an interview :( I am new to this :(....Anthony, it makes sense now, it made me reason now :) Thank you....

Comment: Ok guys, I may be wrong in putting the question. How to add extension method to sealed class ? I understand Sealed means we can derive only right ? :(

Comment: I would note that while `sealed` classes cannot be inherited from, your exampled is merely *called* `Sealed`, and can be used as a base class as normal.

Comment: If your question is how can one create extension methods on a sealed class, then you should ask that.

Comment: Kudos to you Oded, I was confused....My question was that only, how can we create extension method on sealed class and how does it differs from creating extension method on normal class ? The guy in interview confused me when I start telling him how will I create extension method using "this" keyword ...He said its sealed and how do you do here... :( I dont know the answer and thats what I am trying to ask here....May be I was in a little hurry when creating this post, so wrote the topic name incorrectly... uhmmm :(sorry

Comment: I'm not sure what all the fuss and down votes are all about. I thought the *intent* of what Divine was trying to achieve was quite clear.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for considering my real intent. I should be really still better and thoughtful while posting queries with right words or way...I will take a good care on this...I am learning things now and happy :) Cheers...thank you again Kevin...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @ReedCopsey has already pointed out, the way to extend the functionality of a sealed class is with an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).  Here is one that will do what you are asking:

```
public sealed class MyClass       
{ 
    int a; int b;    
    int Add (int x, int y)    
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public static class MyClassExtensions
{
    public static decimal Average(this MyClass value,  int x, int y)
    {
        return (x + y)/2M;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    var myClass = new MyClass();

    // returns 15
    var avg = myClass.Average(10, 20);
```

**EDIT** As requested, here is the all the code.  Create a new Console Application in Visual Studio, replace all the code in the `Program.cs` file with the code below and run.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public sealed class MyClass
    {
        public int X { get; private set; }
        public int Y { get; private set; }

        public MyClass(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        int Add()
        {
            return this.X + this.Y;
        }
    }

    public static class MyClassExtensions
    {
        public static decimal Average(this MyClass value)
        {
            return (value.X + value.Y) / 2M;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass(10, 20);
            var avg = myClass.Average();

            Console.WriteLine(avg);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect this is what I was expecting....EXACTLY....and oh yes now I can recognize when I wrote Average(this int x... interviewer stopped me and said this is sealed class and you can use this way..... So now I got to know from your post how to create extension method on sealed class.....so its different from creating extension method in normal class ? If I have to see the same class as normal class and not sealed, how will the implementation of the same be ? Thank you So much, your answer made me understand better... :)

Comment: Nope, it's not different from creating an extension method for a normal (not sealed) class.  It's exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you Kevin....That was really very much helpful :) Appreciate it :) Cheers

Comment: :Sorry to bother you for silly thing. I tried the above code in my VS. I used the avg and myclass same way as above in Main class, but I see that myClass object dont have Average method :( Anything should I need to do ?

Comment: Make sure you add a reference to the namespace that your `MyClassExtensions` class is in.  E.g. if it is in the `ConsoleApplication1.Extensions` namespace, then add `using ConsoleApplication1.Extensions;` to the top of the file `MyClass` is in.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for the reply, I have all the codes in the same Program class file. Including Main program method. Not sure where I am going wrong..... I will investigate it more.. Thank you so much Kevin for your kind help...I know I am being silly...but I am new to this...:)

Comment: I have just updated the answer.  If it still doesn't work for you, then I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Yay !!! Great thank you so much, it did worked now perfectly :) I am happy that I learnt something. And one last question if you have got sometime or you can please reply me when you get time... I really dont understand the concept of why we have to use "this MyClass value" or what each of these 3 words signifies and being significant...As because I remember writing extension method like Avg(this string name)....where I dint use class name, value like we use here...curious to know the difference or meaning :) Thank you so much again :)

Comment: Why is this an extension method when it doesn't even use `value`?

Comment: I have updated the answer again in response to the above two comments.  @Divine, I would suggest reading up more on Extension Methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you so much.... Both are pretty, but I feel this modified method is little complicated in coding than the earlier.... I go with 1st method ;) Nice nice to know :) Ok I will definitely go through and learn more in detail in the link that you gave above...Thanks a lot Kevin :) Cheers and well wishes... :)

Comment: Cheers and don't forget to accept the answer after all this...  :)

Comment: Oh indeed not. I wanted to accept the moment I understood your program itself.... But it gave me exception that I need to wait for sometime... Anyway done now :) Thank you very much again for your help....:) Cheers....

Answer (score 10):

> Could someone please help me understand the concept of "Extending Sealed class" and its "Real time usage and benefits"

The basic concept is that a sealed class means you cannot subclass (extend) it.  This is the entire reason the class is *sealed* - this "seals" the class so it cannot be extended.

Extension methods allow you to make a method that *appears* to extend the class, but is really a normal static method.  The compiler calls this method, and passes the class instance.

Comment: Thank you so much Reed, I got my eyes open now.... Was blank on this when asked in an interview...He was trying to confuse me in interview :(